# Using the latest Adobe AIR SDK

Tags: android, air, aptana

I downloaded the [latest SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/) to C:\AdobeAIRSDK.  In Aptana Studio, Window, preferences, I added it and checked it (the default AIR SDK is no longer checked).  I then created a new AIR project, but the application.xml file still has

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">
```

I thought I would see 2.6 here.

Comment: Should it be pointing to bin, frameworks, include, install, lib, runtimes, samples, or templates?

Comment: did you follow these directions: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/873/cpsid_87300.html  When you pull down the File menu in Flash you should see "Adobe Air 2.5 settings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have the [current air (2.5 or higher) runtime](http://get.adobe.com/air/) installed. 
I've also updated the [answer for your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757165/adobe-air-for-android-hello-world/5757816#5757816) to contain a link to this air runtime as well.